# Nginx reverse proxy from subdomains to ports

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, subdomain

This is my entire nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        server_name  subsonic.domain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/;
            proxy_set_header Host      $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        }
    }

    # server {
    #     server_name  perforce.domain.com;
    #     location / {
    #         proxy_pass http://localhost:1666/;
    #         proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    #         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #         proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    #     }        
    # }

}
```

I'm on windows 8 and if I uncomment the second server declaration nginx crashes instantly. I've been poking at this for hours trying examples and have no idea why this wont work. Please help, thanks.